# How to make a element to have width 100% if is in a new row?

Tags: html, css, sass, less, tailwind-css

1. I have one flex row, with flex-wrap content
2. One Icon
3. Text which may be huge
4. And Label and Button in the end of the row

Goal is to put Label and Button in the end of the row once when they are moved into new row, cus text is too long.

Really small but complicated issue...

```
   <div
      role="alert"
      className='relative ease-animation max-w-xxs sm:max-w-xs  md:max-w-sm lg:max-w-lg w-max shadow-bottom-lg rounded-md1 my-2 px-5 pb-4 flex items-center flex-wrap'
    >
      <div className="flex w-max mt-4 items-center">        
          <IconComponent  />
        <span
          className='tracking-extratight'
        >
          {text}
        </span>
      </div>
    
      {/* =======>>> Need this div ensure that the THIS DIV is on the right <<<============== */}
      <div className="h-3 w-max mt-3 flex-1 " />
        <div
          className="flex items-center w-auto justify-end self-end ml-3 "
          onClick={onCtaClick}
        >
          <span>
            {ctaText}
          </span>
          <CloseIcon />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you tried w-100 ?

Comment: Yes, then retry and X will be all the time in the new row. 
even if text is small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add css property `margin left: auto` to the 'Retry' Label and you'll see the label and button on the extreme right of the box

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-end` [Bootstrap Text Alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

***NOTE:** CSS is just for demo purpose in this example *

```css
[role="alert"] {
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
max-width:500px;
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <div
      role="alert"
      class='bg-danger rounded relative w-max shadow-bottom-lg rounded-md1 my-2 px-5 pb-4 flex items-center flex-wrap'
    >
      <div class="flex w-max mt-4 items-center">        
          <IconComponent  />
        <span
          className='tracking-extratight'
        >
         There was an issue blablablablablababla !
        </span>
      </div>
    
      
      <div class="h-3 w-max mt-3 flex-1" />
        <div
          class="flex items-center text-end justify-end self-end ml-3 "
          onClick={onCtaClick}
        >
          <span>
            Retry X
          </span>
          <CloseIcon />
        </div>
    </div>
```